# Landscape GUI failed to start after a reboot

Tags: maas, cloud, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I installed Openstack with Ubuntu's Autopilot (openstack-install), and after some fighting, and a lot of help from Ubuntu people, was working fine.
Today I needed to reboot everything, and after the reboot, everything seemed to be fine, all services went up nicely, etc.
The only problem is when I wanted to go to Landscape's GUI, this is what I get:
"Oops!

Sorry for the inconvenience. If you're having trouble filing a support case, please phone us. Support hours are as per your service level agreement."

I restarted apache2 service on Landscape's server (juju-machine-0-lxc-2) and another machine (container) where it has apache2, and it has the IP address where I connect to Landscape's GUI, juju-machine-0-lxc-0. Nothing changed.

`/var/log/landscape/sysinfo.log` is empty in both containers.

juju says that both services are running fine:

```
landscape:
  charm: cs:trusty/landscape-server-3
  can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/landscape-server-6
  exposed: false
  relations:
    amqp:
    - rabbitmq-server
    db-admin:
    - postgresql
    vhost-config:
    - apache2
    website:
    - haproxy
  units:
    landscape/0:
      agent-state: started
      agent-version: 1.20.14
      machine: 0/lxc/2
      public-address: 10.0.3.1


apache2:
  charm: cs:trusty/apache2-4
  can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/apache2-8
  exposed: true
  relations:
    reverseproxy:
    - haproxy
    vhost-config:
    - landscape
  units:
    apache2/0:
      agent-state: started
      agent-version: 1.20.14
      machine: 0/lxc/0
      open-ports:
      - 80/tcp
      - 443/tcp
      public-address: 10.222.221.138
```

Comment: Problem solved. More info at https://askubuntu.com/questions/596004/landscape-is-not-running-after-a-reboot-with-juju-core-1-20-x

Answer (score 2):

Run this command on both landscape/0 and landscape-msg/0:

```
sudo lsctl status
```

Looks like the *landscape* services are down. Or at least the path from *apache* to them, which looks like this:

apache ---> haproxy ---> backend services (app, msg, ping, etc)

Comment: The problem is that 0/lxc/2 (landscape) is taking the **lxcbr0** Ip instead of the eth0 one (10.222.221.140 in m y case). I remember I fix it once, but now I'm facing the same problem again and I don't remember how I fix it. :(