# Computers not reporting to landscape

Tags: juju, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I had working Landscape after installing Openstack with openstack-installer. After some time, and after rebooting everything, and after some struggling with juju ([Landscape is not running after a reboot with juju-core 1.20.x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596004/landscape-is-not-running-after-a-reboot-with-juju-core-1-20-x)), Landscape is running again, as well as Openstack.

The problem is that none computer is reporting to Landscape. I receive every 5 minutes an email with subject "**[Landscape Alert] 18 computers haven't contacted Landscape within the last 5 minutes**", even though all servers are up and running.

I'm facing serious problems on Openstack as well (cant launch new instances, backup volumes, etc) and my guess is the problem is related.

Comment: Please inspect and/or attach a /var/log/landscape/broker.log file from one of the computers that have this alert enabled. It's the log that contains information about the exchanges and will most likely have the reason why they are failing.

Comment: Says something about a cert and stuff: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10593219/

Comment: Looks like your server certificate changed. There used to be a bug in the Apache charm where it would regenerate the certificate, if SELFSIGNED was in use, on every reboot (https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/apache2/+bug/1322759). It's marked "fix released", though.

To validate this theory, can you get us the /var/log/juju/unit-apache2-*.log file from the apache2 unit(s) and the approximate reboot time? Then we can correlate that with the certificate regeneration, if this is indeed what happened.

Comment: Reboot time: 2015-03-11 13:36:46. The log is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10610121/. There are some other reboots: 2015-01-16 14:10:27, and 2015-02-24 18:24:04, but not totally sure.

Comment: Hm, I don't a second certificate generation. Could you paste a copy of the apache2 certificate somewhere? Not the private key, just the public cert. You can obtain it with the command "openssl s_client -connect apache2-ip:443" and extract the BEGIN/END bits what will show up. Then go to a client and get the file pointed at by the ssl_public_key configuration in /etc/landscape/client.conf, it should be the same certificate (paste that one too).

Comment: They are the same cert: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10610400/

Comment: The certificate expired on Feb 11 19:42:34 2015 GMT. Let me think of a juju/charm way to fix it.

Comment: Really? I installed everything on January 2015. That's weird. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, the apache2 charm, when creating self-signed certificates, was ignoring a setting and making the certificate valid for 30 days only. It was fixed on February 25th, 2015. Can you paste the output of juju status of the MAAS environment, the one where Landscape is deployed? That's where the Apache2 service is, and it will tell us what it's charm store revision is and where it came from exactly. Then we can give you instructions on how to upgrade it and get the fixed version. Run, as ubuntu user, "JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju juju status" and paste that output for us.

Comment: There you go! http://paste.ubuntu.com/10611185/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21996/discussion-between-sacha-yunusic-and-andreas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the debugging session via comments to the original question, we found out what the issue is.

When using a self-signed certificate, the apache2 charm had a bug where it would generate such a certificate with only 30 days of validity.

What happened is that it expired. This was fixed in a newer version of the charm, so what we will do is upgrade to that and trigger a new certificate generation.

Please follow these steps to upgrade the charm and regenerate the certificate:

1. Run `juju ssh apache2/0 'sudo rm -f /etc/ssl/certs/apache2.cert /etc/ssl/private/apache2.key /etc/ssl/certs/landscape_server_ca.crt'`.
2. Run `juju upgrade-charm apache2`. This will upgrade the charm, and the new charm, once it sees there are no certificates (deleted in the first step), will generate a new pair.
3. Watch the output of `juju debug-log` until it quiets down.
4. Run `juju ssh apache2/0 'sudo service apache2 restart'` (I will file a bug about this step: it shouldn't be needed, but is right now)

Now we need to tell the clients about this new certificate. This is a bit trickier, because the clients are running in another juju environment which exists on the landscape/0 unit, inception-like. Follow these steps:

1. Grab the new certificate: `juju scp apache2/0:/etc/ssl/certs/apache2.cert .`
2. Make sure permissions are 0644: `chmod 0644 apache2.cert`
3. Verify it expires 10 years from now: `openssl x509 -in apache2.cert -noout -enddate`
4. Upload it to landscape/0: `juju scp apache2.cert landscape/0:/tmp`
5. Login on landscape/0: `juju ssh landscape/0`
6. Change the landscape user shell: `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash landscape`
7. Become landscape: `sudo -u landscape -i`
8. Point to the cloud juju environment: `export JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/$(ls -1t /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/|head -n 1)`
9. Run this to confirm juju is working in that environment: `juju status`. You should see a lot of OpenStack services
10. Tell landscape-client about the new certificate: `juju set landscape-client ssl-public-key="base64:$(cat /tmp/apache2.cert|base64)"`
11. Watch the output of `juju debug-log` until it quiets down
12. Restart landscape-client everywhere: `juju run --service landscape-client 'sudo service landscape-client restart'`
13. If the above command fails with something about subordinate services not being supported, run this instead: `juju run --all 'sudo service landscape-client restart'`

You can login on a client and tail -f the broker.log file, see if the SSL error persists.

Comment: The certificate problem is gone, but there is still some issues. From your procedure, everything went fine, except the deletion of the file /etc/ssl/certs/landscape_server_ca.crt, because it didn't exists. The problems I'm facing now are here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10612838/. Your procedure it was applied at 2015-03-16 20:48:09,269.

Comment: After some rebooting, troubleshooting, etc.. I have several "hook failed: "config-changed"" errors. broker.log looks pretty much the same than the on I pasted in prior comment. Landscape is stuck with 19 tasks like or so doing some synchronization. They are slowly finishing, so I guess it takes time. I'll check it out tomorrow, and work on the failed hooks.

Comment: Those config-changed errors should be fixed. You will have to login to each unit that is in this state and inspect its /var/log/juju/unit-<name>.log file to see why it failed, fix it and run "juju resolved --retry <unitname>".

Comment: ok, I'll do that. Now, in Lanscape there are some tasks runnung for 15 hours or more; some like "Resynchronize computer juju-machine-0-lxc-7 (scopes: disk)", but after that the same task is there again and it was successfull (same task applied to the same host). Should I cancel the first task? Or wait longer to finish the first, even the newer was successful already?

Comment: Ok, I solved all of the errors but one. When I ran "juju resolved --retry mysql/0" the unit tries to download something from archive.ubuntu.com and gives this error: File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-mysql-0/charm/hooks/config-changed", line 114, in <module> // with open('/var/lib/mysql/mysql.passwd','r') as rpw: // IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.passwd'

Comment: ok, at the end I solved with a simple "sudo touch /var/lib/mysql/mysql.passwd". Not very elegant, but it seemed to work. Now I have to move on to the openstack problem, but that's not part of this thread. Thank you very much for your help. Now Landscape is managing those servers without problem.

Comment: If there was no mysql.passwd file, I think this deployment is really broken now. I suggest to start over, unless you really want to dig in for learning purposes.

Comment: I'll reinstall. IS there any way to access the data that is on Volumes on Ceph? I have production data there...