# Why Landscape is not showing package information?

Tags: package-management, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I just install Landscape 15.01 (it came on the testing package of `openstack-install`), and everything is working fine: the nodes are being reported to LDS, but there is no package information.

If I go to LDS → Computers → Packages, I get this message saying “No package information is available for the selected computers”

There is no alerts regarding any miscommunication between the computers and LDS.

If I go to monitoring on any computer, I see it CPU, RAM, everything.. that's why I know (think) computers are reporting to LDS.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an expected limitation while the Landscape Openstack Autopilot is in Beta.  Upgrades cannot be performed and required reboots will not be listed on the machines that make up your Openstack infrastructure.

Until the feature is fully implemented, reboots and upgrades are disabled on these machines.

Other computers will be treated normally, including instances spawned in Openstack itself and registered with Landscape.

Comment: Oh... on LDS 14.01 I was able to patch and reboot machines. Maybe that is different in 15.

Comment: @SachaYunusic:  Yes, you are correct.  This has been removed as it was misrepresenting the capabilities of landscape managing the openstack infrastructure.  It did not work correctly and it is currently planned to be properly fixed in a future release.

Comment: Tell me about it! I put this question regarding that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/596404/computers-not-reporting-to-landscape.