# Landscape + Autopilot Openstack not allowing package management

Tags: apt, juju, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm currently running LDS 16.03 and I'm still unable to see packages of the machines within landscape.  I know it's reporting everything else.  I was able to find a [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605646/why-landscape-is-not-showing-package-information) where it was a known limitation because of the beta of autopilot and 15.01.  There has been 3 LDS releases since then with the latest being 16.03 and I was unable to find in the release notes of 16.03 being a known issue.

Anyone have an update, or report different behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Autopilot turns off this feature currently.  That is by design and updates are currently up to the operator to take care of.  There are plans to change this in the future once the HA service level can be guaranteed while the upgrade is in progress.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll keep an eye open for any changes, it's minor, I was just wondering.